# Change text decoration style for matching tags in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, atom-editor

I have changed the settings in the [highlight-matching-tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag) extension for Visual Studio Code to add an underline to the opening and closing tags in html like so:

```
"highlight-matching-tag.style": {
        "textDecoration": "underline"
    }
```

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGM0H.png). The style is being applied to the entire opening tag along with all its attributes.

Is it possible to change the style to underline only the opening tag and not its attributes like we have in the Atom editor?

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSegY.png) that I trying to accomplish.

Comment: can you show what does the atom editor has for the same setting?

Comment: Its a built in feature in Atom. I don't have any extensions installed.

Comment: I meant look for the same setting in atom. Might help in understanding the problem.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with that extension.

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you want:

```
   "highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
        "opening": {
            "name": {
                "underline": "#8854d0",
            }
        },
        "closing": {
            "name": {
                "underline": "#8854d0"
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Looks like they have made recent major changes to this extension adding a lot of new styling options.

Comment: @Mark Yes - it has become quite useful!